# how to avoid staticmethod in my Python sample

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I want to store sorted instances of Student class, into Students class. And I am using staticmethod in Students class for sorting. I could be wrong, but the design seems a bit ugly and want to avoid using static method (the most ideal way in my mind is using a class method in class Student which returns student ID, and use this method for sorting, but it seems not an easier way to set a class method of class Student in class Students for sorting), if there is a better design, appreciate if you could share,

```
class Student:
        def __init__(self, id):
                self.id = id

class Students:
        def __init__(self, students):
                self.sortedStudents = sorted(students, key=Students.getStudentID)
        @staticmethod
        def getStudentID(student):
                return student.id

        def dumpAllStudents(self):
                for student in self.sortedStudents:
                        print student.id

students = []
students.append(Student(100))
students.append(Student(90))
students.append(Student(80))

allStudents = Students(students)
allStudents.dumpAllStudents()
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I don't understand you code design - why did you create a getter for the Student.id field inside the Students class? The getStudentID method is redundant

Comment: @mittelmania, good point, I can, but how to refer this method in Students class for sorting? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
import operator
...

def __init__(self, students):
    self.sortedStudents = sorted(students, key=operator.attrgetter('id'))
```

`operator.attrgetter('id')` returns a callable that returns the attribute `id` from the operand. So it can be used instead of the static method or `lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) instead:

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, students):
        self.sortedStudents = sorted(students, key=lambda s: s.id)
    ...
```

Whether you want to do this or have your `Student` class itself be comparable (see tzaman's answer) depends a bit on the rest of your code and your intent. If you need an order on students elsewhere, include the ordering in the `Student` class. If you only want them ordered inside your `Students` class, use my approach.

From an OOP design perspective, I wouldn't consider students to be ordered in general, but that's for you to decide (and may in the end be a matter of convenience).

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is just to `sort Student's instance` based on its `id`, you don't need another function or method for that. You can achieve this using [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression.

```
class Student:
        def __init__(self, id):
                self.id = id

class Students:
        def __init__(self, students):
                self.sortedStudents = sorted(students, key=lambda stud: stud.id) 

        def dumpAllStudents(self):
                for student in self.sortedStudents:
                        print student.id

students = []
students.append(Student(100))
students.append(Student(90))
students.append(Student(80))

allStudents = Students(students)
allStudents.dumpAllStudents()
```